# Using both onepage-scroll.js and scrollReveal.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to use both [scrollReveal.js](https://github.com/julianlloyd/scrollReveal.js) and [onepage-scroll.js](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll)

scrollReveal is suposed to animate elements when the browser displays them. onepage-scroll helps to "fake" a one page website.

Seems like there is a conflict between them : scrollReveal inits *well on load* but doesn't work at all when I "scroll down" to another "page" (onepage-scroll's role)

Here is a snippet :

```js
/* scrollReveal implementation */
var srConf = {
    opacity: 1,
    reset: true,
    delay: "always"
};
var sr = window.sr = new scrollReveal(srConf);


/* onepage-scroll implementation */
$("#onepage-scroll").onepage_scroll({
    animationTime: 800,
    pagination: false, // I use a custom-made nav
    loop: false,
    beforeMove: function(index) {
      /* makes nav working */
        $("#desktop-navbar li.link.on").removeClass("on");
        $("#mobile-navbar li.link.on").removeClass("on");
        $("#desktop-navbar li.link").eq(index-1).addClass("on");
        $("#mobile-navbar li.link").eq(index-1).addClass("on");
    },
    afterMove: function(index) {
      // this is a try - not working
      $(document).trigger("scroll");
    }
});


$(document).on("click", ".navbar li.link", function() {
  /* programmatically "scroll" to another page */
    $("#onepage-scroll").moveTo($(this).index()+1);
});
```

```css
body #desktop-navbar-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 900;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
body #desktop-navbar-container ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: inherit;
}
body #desktop-navbar-container ul li.link {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
body #desktop-navbar-container ul li.link:hover,
body #desktop-navbar-container ul li.link.on {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
body #desktop-navbar-container ul li.link i.fa {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://www.pskowron.info/css/onepage-scroll.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="content">
  <div id="desktop-navbar-container" class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
    <ul id="desktop-navbar" class="navbar">
      <li class="link on">Page 1</li>
      <li class="link">Page 2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="onepage-scroll">
  <section id="page1">
    <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: blue;" data-sr="enter top over 0.9s"></div>
    <div style="width: 350px; height: 80px; background-color: red;" data-sr="enter left over 0.4s wait 1s"></div>
  </section>
  
  <section id="page2">
    <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: blue;" data-sr="enter top over 0.9s"></div>
    <div style="width: 350px; height: 80px; background-color: red;" data-sr="enter bottom over 0.4s wait 1s"></div>
  </section>
</div>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.pskowron.info/js/jquery.onepage-scroll.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.pskowron.info/js/scrollReveal.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason of it, is that onepage-scroll doesn't really scroll the site but changes the `translate3d` property of the plugin's container.

You can use scrollReveal if you want with [fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) by [using the option `scrollBar:true`](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrollBar.html) which will force the plugin to show an scroll bar and therefore to work using the real scrolling feature provided by the browser.

In any case, you wouldn't need to use `scrollReveal` as you can always use the callbacks provided by the plugin such as `afterLoad` or `afterSlideLoad`.